# How to revert my last action comprising few tasks in Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there any way to revert (undo) my last action which comprises sorting, removing duplicates and protecting data. Currently I am doing all these three tasks together by pressing a submenu in Google Sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**View or revert to earlier versions**

Note: You need Owner or Editor access to see the version history.

In Drive, open your file.

1. Click File and then Version history and then See version history.
2. Click a timestamp to see a previous version of the file.

Below the timestamp, you’ll see:

- Names of people who edited the document
- A color next to each person’s name. The edits they made appear in
  that color

To revert to this version, click **Restore this version.**

> **Reference**: [Link](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308971?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Is it possible to code the Undo process using Apps Script?

Comment: Why looking for a sophisticated solution, when there is an easy one. Sometimes keeping things as simple as possible is much better (safer), even if you experience some excitement by '_pressing a submenu_' as you said to automate all what you're doing.